# Call to undefined function imagerotate()

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I have a strange error here, I think.

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagerotate() in
>   /var/www/web/html/include/php/class/image.class.php
>   on line 30

***LINE 30:***

```
$im = imagerotate( $this->res, $degrees, $bkg );
```

According to [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php), `imagerotate()` should be a function since PHP 4 and I am using PHP 5.

Why does it not work? Other image functions, such as `imagecreatefromjpeg()` and `imagejpeg()`  work fine.

**GD info from phpinfo():**

GD Support  **enabled**
GD Version  **2.0 or higher**
FreeType Support    **enabled**
FreeType Linkage    **with freetype**
FreeType Version    **2.3.7**
T1Lib Support   **enabled**
GIF Read Support    **enabled**
GIF Create Support  **enabled**
JPG Support     **enabled**
PNG Support     **enabled**
WBMP Support    **enabled**

Comment: `Note: This function is only available if PHP is compiled with the bundled version of the GD library.` What does a `phpinfo()` say about your gd library?

Comment: GD Support is enabled, see full info from phpinfo() on GD in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) you linked to it clearly says

> Note: This function is only available
>   if PHP is compiled with the bundled
>   version of the GD library.

And one of the [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php#95749) say

> This function apparently contains a
>   memory leak. Because of this, it was
>   kept out of the GD library that comes
>   with Ubuntu (and I assume other OS'es,
>   too).
>
> So, If you are running Ubuntu and
>   wonder why you get "Call to undefined
>   function imagerotate()" even though
>   you seemingly have the correct GD lib
>   installed, this is why. Use the
>   alternative supplied by beau at
>   dragonflydevelopment dot com instead.
>   It works flawlessly (for angles in
>   steps of 90 degrees).
>
> On a side-note, some other GD image
>   functions (unfortunately, the more
>   interesting ones) suffer from the same
>   problem and are kept out of the Ubuntu
>   distribution as well.

For a possible solution look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php#93151)

Code copied from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php#93151 and revised

```
if (!function_exists('imagerotate')) {

    /*
        Imagerotate replacement. ignore_transparent is work for png images
        Also, have some standard functions for 90, 180 and 270 degrees.
        Rotation is clockwise
    */

    function imagerotate_rotateX($x, $y, $theta) {
        return $x * cos($theta) - $y * sin($theta);
    }

    function imagerotate_rotateY($x, $y, $theta) {
        return $x * sin($theta) + $y * cos($theta);
    }

    function imagerotate($srcImg, $angle, $bgcolor = 0, $ignore_transparent = 0) {
        $srcw = imagesx($srcImg);
        $srch = imagesy($srcImg);

        //Normalize angle
        $angle %= 360;
        //Set rotate to clockwise
        $angle = -$angle;

        if ($angle == 0) {
            if ($ignore_transparent == 0) {
                imagesavealpha($srcImg, true);
            }
            return $srcImg;
        }

        // Convert the angle to radians
        $theta = deg2rad($angle);

        //Standart case of rotate
        if ((abs($angle) == 90) || (abs($angle) == 270)) {
            $width = $srch;
            $height = $srcw;
            if (($angle == 90) || ($angle == -270)) {
                $minX = 0;
                $maxX = $width;
                $minY = -$height+1;
                $maxY = 1;
            } else if (($angle == -90) || ($angle == 270)) {
                $minX = -$width+1;
                $maxX = 1;
                $minY = 0;
                $maxY = $height;
            }
        } else if (abs($angle) === 180) {
            $width = $srcw;
            $height = $srch;
            $minX = -$width+1;
            $maxX = 1;
            $minY = -$height+1;
            $maxY = 1;
        } else {
            // Calculate the width of the destination image.
            $temp = array(
                imagerotate_rotateX(0, 0, 0 - $theta),
                imagerotate_rotateX($srcw, 0, 0 - $theta),
                imagerotate_rotateX(0, $srch, 0 - $theta),
                imagerotate_rotateX($srcw, $srch, 0 - $theta)
            );
            $minX = floor(min($temp));
            $maxX = ceil(max($temp));
            $width = $maxX - $minX;

            // Calculate the height of the destination image.
            $temp = array(
                imagerotate_rotateY(0, 0, 0 - $theta),
                imagerotate_rotateY($srcw, 0, 0 - $theta),
                imagerotate_rotateY(0, $srch, 0 - $theta),
                imagerotate_rotateY($srcw, $srch, 0 - $theta)
            );
            $minY = floor(min($temp));
            $maxY = ceil(max($temp));
            $height = $maxY - $minY;
        }

        $destimg = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        if ($ignore_transparent == 0) {
            imagefill($destimg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($destimg, 255,255, 255, 127));
            imagesavealpha($destimg, true);
        }

        // sets all pixels in the new image
        for ($x = $minX; $x < $maxX; $x++) {
            for ($y = $minY; $y < $maxY; $y++) {
                // fetch corresponding pixel from the source image
                $srcX = round(imagerotate_rotateX($x, $y, $theta));
                $srcY = round(imagerotate_rotateY($x, $y, $theta));
                if ($srcX >= 0 && $srcX < $srcw && $srcY >= 0 && $srcY < $srch) {
                    $color = imagecolorat($srcImg, $srcX, $srcY);
                } else {
                    $color = $bgcolor;
                }
                imagesetpixel($destimg, $x-$minX, $y-$minY, $color);
            }
        }

        return $destimg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Must be Ubuntu my host uses, but the code you copied worked flawless.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Ubuntu by any chance? Then [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php#95749) might explain why you get the error message.

Comment: That would be my guess. Been caught out by this on Ubuntu before, and I believe the same applies to Debian. [Here's the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/74647) (though it's not considered a bug by many) and associated discussion, with more background info.

Answer (score 1):

First add to your script an if:

```
if(!extension_loaded('gd'))
             throw new Exception('GD extenstion not installed');
```

If its working check out your GD info by:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(gd_info());
```

And also check that jpeg is supported (it should be in dg_info results).

If it's all okay and it's still don't works, ask your hosting service.

(Error says that you using non existing function, cna you pase some code where you are using it?)